# How to convert 'ls' command to 'cat' command?

Tags: c, linux, bash, shell

I am trying to solve this problem, I am only allowed to run *ls* command and my objective is to read the flag. There is a vulnerable C code which has *setuid*.

```
    -rwsr-sr-x 1 lameprogrammer lameprogrammer 8579 Sep 15 07:21 vul_c
    -rw-r----- 1 lameprogrammer lameprogrammer  154 Sep 15 07:40 flag
```

I am user **attacker** and I have to read this flag file. The given C code is

```
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <stdio.h>

    #define FILENAME "/var/challenges/attacker/challenge1/flag"

    int main(void)
    {
        int vert;
        vert = system("ls " FILENAME);
        if(!vert)
            puts("Flag is at " FILENAME " :P ");
        else
            puts("Sorry! no file is there");
    }
```

I was trying to convert *ls* into *cat* so that if that runs then it will read the **flag** file. To do that I copied all the bin folder into my local space and then I replaced *ls* with *cat* and then exported the new PATH. Technically it should replace and my *ls* command should work like *cat* but it is not working. The following are my command :

```
   cp -r /bin /home/attacker
   cd /home/attacker/bin
   rm ls
   cp cat ls
   export PATH=/home/attacker/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/games
```

The *ls* command is not working as *cat* and output is:

```
   ls: unrecognized option '--color=auto'
   Try 'ls --help' for more information.
```

When I am trying to run ./vul_c it says permission denied and then it is printing *Sorry! no file is there*.

Any help onto this would be great.

Comment: But the whole point of the competition is that you beat other people.  Not we beat them and you take the credit.

Comment: The competition is over. I just want to solve that and see where I went wrong.

Comment: You said "I am playing a CTF competition."  I guess you can see why we might take that to mean you are playing it now, as opposed to you failed to complete it in the past.

Comment: It might be that there's an alias somewhere for `ls` to be `ls --color=auto`. Which is info `cat` doesn't understand. Check your .bashrc or other config files like that for this.

Comment: @JohnZwinck  Sorry for my English. I messed up there.

Comment: @HoriaComan Since I am not root user, so I won't be able to make change in .bashrc file. Moreover, there is no such info about that.

Comment: If you code in C you should consider using [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) and [readdir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html)

Comment: I get the exact same error message if I do "`cat --color=auto /etc/os-release`". If you can't get rid of the --color option, and can't use /bin/cat as a replacement ls because of it, why not just write your own replacement ls?

Comment: @aschepler Thank you, but I tried this by writing a simple C program, but then I am getting permission denied error, even though the program is running with the user (owner) permission and must be able to read the flag. But then I need to run with `./ls`, else it is giving *Segmentation fault (core dumped)*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are in the right direction but you are just putting too much effort for this small thing. Instead of creating a program why don't you create a symlink and then point this to `cat`.

Try this step:

```
   ln -s /bin/cat ls
```

Finally, export this and I hope you will be done with your solution. In this, you don't even have to worry about permission. Let me know if it works.

Comment: This only works if `.` is in `$PATH` before `/bin`, which it shouldn't be. And what do you mean by "Finally, export this"?

Answer (score 3):

Does the *program* work? The problem as I see it is that if you use `ls` in the *shell*, is that it has an alias that will enable the colouring, i.e. something like

```
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
```

Now this is something that `cat` wouldn't understand. But it would be only for *your* shell, not the `ls` command run by that script, because it wouldn't use the aliases. Perhaps something like `unalias ls` would help in the shell.

Now, the `system` function cannot run your `ls` because it doesn't have proper rights - you forgot to `chmod +x ls`.

Comment: While I was using `cp` command it copies with the executable permission. Even though I tried your way and did `chmod +x ls` but still the problem is same. I cannot use `ls` command as `cat` and read any normal file as well.

Comment: Temporarily moving `~/.bashrc` out of the way would probably fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following command:

```
unalias ls
```

Comment: If you provided some explanation of how this solves the problem, you wouldn't need to pad your answer.